# Rails: Fragment cache how to update when old data is not match with new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, server, memcached

The problem is that I have a function call inside cache fragment which is dependent on the current time and it loads the correct data first time but not always. Some data I need to show is based on time but due to the use of the cache, it just loads old data since the record is not updated. Any idea how can I do that while still using cache.

```
<% cache "shop_items_page_#{@shop.cache_key}" do %>
 ...
   <% cache "item_list_page_#{item.cache_key}_#{shop_cache(item)}" do %>
     ...
     is_item_closed?(item) #a function returns true or false based on time
     ...
   <%end%>
 ...
<%end%>
```

Comment: Are `@show` and `item` instances of ActiveRecord models?

Comment: @Yakov yes they are instances of ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Please show us what `is_item_closed?` does. If it's something that uses `Time.now`, it won't work. If what's in the cache block depends on things that change outside of the model, item in your case, you will need to add those to the cache key. Ex: `cache [:item_list_page, item, Date.current] do`

Comment: @razvans yes `is_item_closed?` is dependent on `Time.now`, it checks `Time.now` with `item.end_time` . What helps me is to append a uniq value in the cache line
`<% cache "shop_items_page_#{@shop.cache_key}#{get_status_code(@shop)}" do %>` 
and 
`<% cache "item_list_page_#{item.cache_key}_#{shop_cache(item)}#{get_status_code(item)}" do %>`  to genrate the new key

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching), you can pass an instance of a model to `cache` method: `cache @shop` and `cache item`. Then Rails will build a cache key based on `updated_at` fields, make sure that you have this field in your tables.
If you strictly need to use custom cache keys, then add `updated_at` directly in the view or inside `cache_key` methods.

```
<% cache "shop_items_page_#{@shop.cache_key}_#{@shop.updated_at}" do %>
 ...
   <% cache "item_list_page_#{item.cache_key}_#{item.updated_at}_#{shop_cache(item)}" do %>
     ...
     is_item_closed?(item) #a function returns true or false based on time
     ...
   <%end%>
 ...
<%end%>
```